# Playback control for youtube video while in PiP mode on mac

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, microsoft-edge

I frequently watch tutorial on youtube and picture in picture mode really become useful.

But I am having issue playing picture in picture mode. I can't use left/right arrow to forward/backward the video. Space bar works though to stop the video.

When I go to the browser and youtube and use left/right arrow it works and also forward/backwards the video in picture in picture mode. But I am not able to do show on the window of picture in picture mode.

I am using edge browser on m1.

Comment: Are you updated? Check to make sure: edge://about Edit: It's in settings> About Microsoft Edge, if link fails you.

Comment: I just updated still there is no option control playback except play/pause.